# Не могу попасть в Spring контроллер

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, spring-mvc, java-ee

Пробовал сделать простой Spring MVC проект и запустить его через TomCat. Проект в TomCat деплоится успешно, но перейти на `http://localhost:8080/hello` не выходит, пишет "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists". Чтобы понять в чем проблема добавил простой `System.out.println("Я попал в контроллер")` в метод контроллера, но когда пытаешься попасть по адресу, то даже в консоли ничего не выводит.

Структура проекта

[image: Структура проекта]

Конфигурационный файл Spring-а

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vashchenko.app"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Конфигурационный файл Dispatcher-а

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-app1</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering/>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Класс контроллера

```
package com.vashchenko.app.controllers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Я попал в контроллер");
        return "hello_world";
    }
}
```

и сам pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringApp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <springVersion>6.0.10</springVersion>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.20</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.20</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

При создании конфигурации для TomCat все закидываю правильно, поэтому это точно не ошибка в url-адресе.
Вот сама конфигурация
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже все перебрал и не могу понять в чем проблема

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте файл hello_world.html положить в папку resources/templates. Папку templates нужно создать самостоятельно. Это особенность спринга: когда используем шаблонизаторы, то файлы представлений будут искаться в resources/templates.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-template-directory

"By default, Spring Boot looks for our templates in ***src/main/resources/templates***. We can put our templates there and organize them in sub-directories and have no issues"

Comment: Тут проблема более глобальная, чем отсутствие нужного представления. Я не попадаю в сам метод контроллера sayHello(). Если бы не было представления, то в консоль выводилась бы надпись "Я попал в контролллер" и после ошибка из-за отсутствия представления. А в итоге в консоли у меня ноль, потому что я не попадаю в сам метод

Comment: Так у Вас же пишет "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists" Это как раз сообщение по поводу представления. Попробуйте сначала с этим разобраться. Ведь на данный момент он именно из-за этого ругается.

Comment: С представлением все в порядке. И я не использую Spring Boot, поэтому путь к ним абсолютно верно прописан.